# Excel VBA: copy and divide rows based on date/time criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transform a file with a log of operations in a three-shift production environment to be able to group them by shifts (const 7-15, 15-23, 23-7), i.e. if both the start date/time and the end date/time of the record are not within the same shift then duplicate the row below and change the original end date/time and duplicated end date/time to the corresponding shift end.

```
Event   Start date/time    End date/time      Shift Start    Shift End
A       18/05/2017 4:30    18/05/2017 11:45   Mid (23-7)     Day (7-15)
```

*transforming to:*

```
Event   Start date/time    End date/time      Shift Start    Shift End
A       18/05/2017 4:30    18/05/2017 7:00    Mid (23-7)     Mid (23-7)
A       18/05/2017 7:00    18/05/2017 11:45   Day (7-15)     Day (7-15)
```

---

Unfortunately I am not good enough with VBA, so at the beginning I was trying to solve that using solely excel formulas, and added a column that shows how many shifts the event lasted (what is equal to the X number of rows that have to be doubled), that may be helpful with iterations.

```
Event    Start date/time    End date/time     Shift Start    Shift End    X
A        18/05/2017 4:30    18/05/2017 23:30  Mid (23-7)     Mid (23-7)   3
```

*Logic behind:*

```
Event    Start date/time    End date/time     Shift Start    Shift End    X
A        18/05/2017 4:30    18/05/2017 7:00   Mid (23-7)     Mid (23-7)   ""
A        18/05/2017 7:00    18/05/2017 23:30  Day (7-15)     Mid (23-7)   2
```

*expected result:*

```
Event    Start date/time    End date/time     Shift Start    Shift End    X
A        18/05/2017 4:30    18/05/2017 7:00   Mid (23-7)     Mid (23-7)   ""
A        18/05/2017 7:00    18/05/2017 15:00  Day (7-15)     Day (7-15)   ""
A        18/05/2017 15:00   18/05/2017 23:00  Aft (15-23)    Aft (15-23)  ""
A        18/05/2017 23:00   18/05/2017 23:30  Mid (23-7)     Mid (23-7)   ""
```

I’ve been trying to solve that for hours sourcing the internet, and eventually I have only been able to duplicate the row X-number of times below leaving column F blank, but I feel like it’s a dead end. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
Sub duplicate()
Dim lngRow As Long, copyRows As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lngRow = 2 '1. header
Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & lngRow))
    If Range("F" & lngRow).Value >= 1 Then 'check if the row should be duplicate
        copyRows = Range("F" & lngRow).Value
        Range("F" & lngRow + 1 & ":F" & lngRow + copyRows).EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A" & lngRow & ":F" & (lngRow + copyRows)).FillDown 'was just testing the code. here I think I should work on cells and defined const. do I need an array to solve that problem?
        Range("F" & lngRow & ":F" & (lngRow + copyRows)).Value = ""
        lngRow = lngRow + copyRows
    End If
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2** *this is my first code I have ever written, sorry for any mistakes. I know it's not the cleanest code, but I try my best.*

```
Sub duplicate2()
Dim lngRow As Long, copyRows As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lngRow = 2 '1. header
Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & lngRow))
    If Range("F" & lngRow).Value >= 1 Then 'check if the row should be duplicated
        copyRows = Range("F" & lngRow).Value 'ok
        Range("F" & lngRow + 1 & ":F" & lngRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert 'insert a row below
        Range("F" & lngRow + 1 & ":F" & lngRow + 1).Value = copyRows - 1 'decrease X by 1
        Range("F" & lngRow & ":F" & lngRow).Value = "" 'clean original X
        Range("A" & lngRow + 1 & ":E" & lngRow + 1).FillDown 'duplicate row

        'here I should work on cells and defined const. do I need an array to solve that problem?

    End If
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub duplicate()
Dim lngRow As Long, copyRows As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lngRow = 2 '1. header
Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & lngRow))
    If Range("F" & lngRow).Value >= 1 Then 'check if the row should be duplicate
        copyRows = Range("F" & lngRow).Value
        Range("F" & lngRow + 1 & ":F" & lngRow + copyRows).EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A" & lngRow & ":F" & (lngRow + copyRows)).FillDown 'was just testing the code. here I think I should work on cells and defined const. do I need an array to solve that problem?
        Range("F" & lngRow & ":F" & (lngRow + copyRows)).Value = ""
        lngRow = lngRow + copyRows
    End If
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please show us what code you've tried so far?

Comment: The problem is very well stated. But still, you need to show some code that you have tried with a comprehensive description of the encountered problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I added my dead end below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this macro to split the rows by shift. Uses only columns A-C without using your additional helper columns. It can handles durations that can span many days, because it handles the dates and calculates the shifts precisely using a dedicated function (see the utility function `shifEnd` below).

```
Sub SplitShifts()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
  On Error GoTo Cleanup

  Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("A2:F2")
  Do Until Len(Trim(r(1))) = 0 ' loop until row is empty
    If shiftEnd(r(2)) >= r(3) Then
      Set r = r.Offset(1) ' no split needed, next row
    Else ' insert new row and split shifts
      r.Copy: r.Insert Shift:=xlDown
      r(2) = shiftEnd(r(2))
      r(0, 3) = r(2)
    End If
  Loop

Cleanup:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Function shiftEnd(ByVal d As Date) As Date
  Select Case Hour(d)
    Case 0 To 6: shiftEnd = Int(d) + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)
    Case 7 To 14: shiftEnd = Int(d) + TimeSerial(15, 0, 0)
    Case 15 To 22: shiftEnd = Int(d) + TimeSerial(23, 0, 0)
    Case 23: shiftEnd = Int(d) + 1 + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0) ' Next day 7:00
  End Select
End Function
```

---

**Testing**

```
Event   Start date      End date
A       5/18/17 4:30    5/18/17 21:18
B       5/20/17 18:54   5/22/17 2:06
C       5/22/17 11:42   5/23/17 6:54
D       5/25/17 16:30   5/26/17 6:54
E       5/26/17 4:30    5/26/17 18:54
F       5/27/17 4:30    5/28/17 14:06
G       5/30/17 16:30   5/31/17 23:42
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Eventually I'd managed to solve my problem myself by tweaking my original code minutes before I've seen your answer, but that's so clean. Works faster and doesn't need any additional columns. Thank you for that new perspective!